# How exactly are extra votes gained after you hit your daily vote limit?

Tags: support, voting

I noticed that when I already used all of my daily up-/down-votes I can still vote sometimes and again receive the message

> Daily vote limit reached. Vote again in *<x-time>*.

So there seems an underlying mechanism that lets you regain votes somehow.

Is that because posts you voted on were deleted?

---

As @Makoto [pointed out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355892/how-exactly-extra-votes-are-gained-after-you-hit-your-daily-vote-limit#comment509520_355892) there's already a [FAQ at Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213/175248).
But aren't those limits site specific?

How exactly are these extra votes calculated by the Stack Overflow engine?

Comment: [Uber-meta dupe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213/175248)

Comment: @Makoto I already wondered why I can't find that question here. THX. Voting limits are site specific though, no?

Comment: Up/down voting limits are the same network-wide.

Answer (score 4):

If a post is deleted that you voted on, you will regain another vote. This is for up/down votes not close votes.

> [If the post is deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/what-are-the-limits-on-how-i-can-cast-change-and-retract-votes/5213#5213) the same day as your post vote was cast, you
>   get that post vote back again. Therefore the number of possible post
>   votes available can exceed the normal thirty to forty if there are
>   deletions.