# Why do auto upvotes on close vote comments count towards the daily limit?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review-queues, comments, upvotes

I understand that SO (or entire SE for that matter) has imposed a limit on number of upvotes one can cast in a day because of the policy to rate limit *everything* and it seems reasonable. The limit is somewhere around 40 upvotes a day (for comments) and hence is not that big of an issue.

But yesterday I was close voting many off-topic questions from the review queue. And many of them had Other > not related to programming as a reason. 
On most of these someone had already close voted for the same reason. As a result my close vote led to an auto upvote on the said comment.

I closed around 30-35 questions and it caused me to hit the upvote limit and I couldn't upvote *any* comment for the rest of my day.

Should these auto upvotes be added towards the total limit considering I have no control over them? As a side note I also cannot undo this upvote making it impossible to cast even a single vote.

I would also like to clarify that not counting this towards the total tally doesn't open the system to any kind of abuse since the total number of close votes themselves are rate limited.

At the same time I am also worried if the comments also count towards the comment limit.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355892/how-exactly-are-extra-votes-gained-after-you-hit-your-daily-vote-limit

Comment: IMO, it should only count against the close/flag limit

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you hit your upvote limit then vote to close a question, do you still auto-upvote the close-vote comment?

Comment: @LordFarquaad No, few of my last close votes didn't cast an auto upvote. But it didn't complain explicitly too.

Comment: Honestly, I feel like being limited in the number of _comments_ one can up-vote is the least of my worries. Even if we agree that auto-up-votes shouldn't count against your limit, the quality of the content on the site is hardly affected by even the tiniest amount by our inability to cast a comment vote. This doesn't seem like the kind of problem anyone needs to spend any time on.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Why? Mostly oversight, probably. :)

But, starting with the next prod build, these comment votes will be excluded from the daily comment vote limit. The close vote limit is unchanged.

Comment: Was this done only for Stack Overflow, or across the whole network? (Asking because it's posted in a per-site meta hinting it's unique to the site.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard It's network-wide. Posted in a per-site meta because this is where the report was posted. The change is already included in the Recent Feature Changes post on MSE.